# hide the clicked button when navigated to another page

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have two buttons, (details and open). when I click on details button, it will navigate to details.html file but here the details page appears again. I want to hide the details button when I navigate to another page.

```
 <button mat-button (click)="onSelectApp(app)"><mat-icon class="mat-icon material-icons">pageview</mat-icon>Detail</button>
 <button mat-button (click)="onOpenApp(app.uri)"><mat-icon class="mat-icon material-icons">open_in_new</mat-icon>Open</button>
```

here is the ts code.

```
onSelectApp(app: IApp): void {
if (app.identifier) {
  this.router.navigate(['/home/apps', app.identifier]);
} else {
  console.error('No appId found');
}
```

}

Comment: Assuming the navigation works, you still see the buttons because your /home/apps page contains the component that has those buttons. Is that intentional? If so a way to hide them would be to check if an app.identifier was passed through, and put an *ngIf on the button to hide if it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to hide the button with a simple ngIf statement on the button tag.

```
<button mat-button *ngIf="!app.identifier" (click)="onSelectApp(app)"><mat-icon class="mat-icon material-
    icons">pageview</mat-icon>Detail</button>
```

Comment: If I click on "details" button, then it will navigate to "/home/apps". In /home/apps page, we will see the same mat-card with same data along with other data. but I want to hide only "details" button after navigating to /home/apps page. After using "*ngIf="!app.identifier", I can not see anymore the mat-card in "/home/apps" page.